# PHP Jump to folder number

Tags: php

I have this code that lists all the folders in a directory and numbers each folder, but my desire is to be able to go to a specific folder when I want to start, for example:

The code listed all folders after that done, I would like to go to folder 40 how do I get the path of folder number 40 ? I would like to write a file there.

I thought about putting the folders in an array, but there is nothing simpler where I don't need to use an array because it will be a very large directory I will make a repository.

List folder source:

```
$foldercount = 0;
foreach (glob("folderlist/") as $folder) {
  $foldercount++; 
}
```

Comment: _"I thought about putting the folders in an array, but there is nothing simpler"_ - Not sure what would be simpler than just putting it in an array? And how many folders are we talking about? Thousands? Tens of thousands? But why would you want to use a numeric value to reference them instead of just using the name? It feels like it could be prone to race conditions If a folder gets added or removed while you're running your script. If you then use the numeric reference between requests could reference the wrong folder.

Answer (score 1):

The glob function is already an array, so to access the folder you want just refer to its index number like this:

```
glob("folderlist/")[2]
```

It would look something like this:

```
$folderList  = glob("folderlist/");
$foldercount = 0;
foreach ($folderList) as $folder) {
  $foldercount++; 
}

echo("The last folder is: ".$folderList[$foldercount -1]);
```

p.s
If you only need to list folders I think you would want to use the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag to avoid listing files,
like this:

```
$folderList  = glob("folderlist/", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
```

Comment: The foreach is unnecessary. Just do `$foldercount = count($folderList);` instead.